# Color transform algorithm (that also works on saturation and value/lightness)?

Tags: transformations, algorithm, color

To change particular colors in an image, generally you multiply the RGB by a transformation matrix. Image manipulation programs such as gimp & photoshop have a selective color change function that allows a user to convert pixels within a certain "distance" to the original color in some color space to a new color. Eg, changing `#00f` blue into `#ffd` pale yellow.

I'm trying to implement such a function in a `<canvas>`. What color space and distance definition do these algorithms typically use, and then how do they compute the transformation matrix?

Comment: OK, made the edit.

Comment: Is it understandable now?

Comment: Yes, it's way more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Very often, the [Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) color space is used, since it is close to how humans perceive color. As to which distance to apply: This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#LAB_Delta_E) mentions a Delta E distance of 1.0 for a just noticeable difference. There are a lot of different formulas resulting in different thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

I find the hue/saturation or luminance/chrominance spaces to be fairly easy to work in. They follow our intuitive sense of how color works, even if they're not as scientifically accurate as Lab is. The [conversion from RGB to YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#YCbCr) is a simple matrix multiply. Working in YCbCr would allow you to do things like keep luminance constant while changing hue and/or saturation. You can think of saturation as the distance of the color from the luminance axis (so just the magnitude of CbCr = sqrt(Cb x Cb + Cr x Cr)). The hue is the angle the color point makes with the x-axis when projected onto the CbCr plane. (So you can use atan2(Cr, Cb).) Once you've modified your values, converting back to RGB is another matrix multiply.